const_load_suppressor.rb:55:in `klass': The constant Admin is not loaded yet upon the execution of the RailsAdmin initializer. (RuntimeError)
I have been using RailsAdmin with basic UserName/Password authentication. We recently moved to Devise for authentication and have our Model named Admin.
Here's the error message,
Exiting
/Users/preethi/Development/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rails_admin-3.1.1/lib/rails_admin/config/const_load_suppressor.rb:55:in `klass': The constant Admin is not loaded yet upon the execution of the RailsAdmin initializer. (RuntimeError)
We don't recommend to do this and may lead to issues, but if you really have to do so you can explicitly require it by adding:

  require 'admin'

on top of config/initializers/rails_admin.rb.

I tried adding require 'admin' to my rails_admin.rb file & then it tells me ApplicationRecord is not loaded. It keeps throwing new RunTimeErrors. Anyone faced anything similar?
